# Web scraping, figuring out path

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some info from this page http://biz.yahoo.com/research/earncal/20151208.html

I first try to scrape just the first company name `ABM Industries Inc`, but I get and empty list, and can't figure out why.

```
from lxml import html
import requests   

def symbol_scrape(date): #20151208
    path = 'http://biz.yahoo.com/research/earncal/'+str(date)+'.html'

    page = requests.get(path)
    tree=html.fromstring(page.text)

    comp = tree.xpath('//body//p//table[@border="0"]//tr//td[@valign="top"]//table[@cellpadding="2"]//tr[3]//td[1]/text()')


    return comp
```

Comment: where does the `from_string` function comes from?

Comment: its a part of html package

Answer (score 1):

`comp = tree.xpath('//table[@border="0"]//tr//td[@valign="top"]//table[@cellpadding="2"]//tr[3]//td[1]/text()')` works.

So getting rid of `//body//p` solved tho problem